# What does `[]` do in a regex?

Tags: regex

This webpage contains a number of regexes containing `[]`:

http://mmcif.wwpdb.org/dictionaries/ascii/mmcif_pdbx_v40.dic

An example:

```
[][_,.;:"&<>()/\{}'`~!@#$%A-Za-z0-9*|+-]*
```

The page provides this comment regarding the particular flavor of regexes being used:

> The regular expressions defined here are not compliant
>   with the POSIX 1003.2 standard as they include the
>   '\n' and '\t' special characters.  These regular expressions
>   have been tested using version 0.12 of Richard Stallman's
>   GNU regular expression library in POSIX mode.

What does the `[]` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patterns are written this way to avoid the need to escape the `]` character (and also the hyphen) within the character class being defined.

Un-escaped, `]` closes a character class.  However, if you follow `[` immediately with `]`, it is a special construction that indicates that the 'closing square bracket' is to be included in the character class.

Similarly, once you have opened a character class with `[`, further use of `[` indicates to include 'opening square bracket' in the character class, since "nested character classes" are not allowed.

The location of the hyphen (`-`) at the very end of the class definition also is a special use case, as otherwise use of a hyphen within a character class represents a range of characters to include in the class.

So, the Regex engine parses your sample pattern as:

```
[ {open the character class}
] {include closing bracket}
[_,.;:"&<>()/\{}'`~!@#$%A-Za-z0-9*|+ {include a bunch of characters; [().*{}|+, etc. are not special characters within a class definition}
- {include hyphen}
] {close the character class}
* {zero or more repetitions of the class}
```

Answer (score 1):

When immediately following the opening square bracket, the closing one just means itself `]`. The next opening square bracket is also simply meaning its own character `[`.

```
$ echo "a[b" | grep '[]]'
$ echo "a[b" | grep '[[]' 
a[b
$ echo "a[b" | grep '[]'  
grep: Unmatched [ or [^
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, [] means nothing, brackets are used to define ranges of chars. An empty range means nothing.

Now, looking at the change log in your link...

> 1.048 2007-11-18
>
> Changes: (jdw/kh)
>
> - add '[]' to allowed characters for data types code and ucode -